# View Bulk Operation with custom action

Tags: views, nodes, 9

I have a custom action to update some table values base on node content selection. My custom actions are listed correctly on bulk update select box. But I can perform operation some random node content only. Any thoughts!! why It's allow actions to perform on some contents only.

View Bulk Operation: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations

Tried Version: 8.x-3.13 , 4.0.0-rc1

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_user\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\views_bulk_operations\Action\ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;

/**
 * Content moderation publish node.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "notification_read",
 *   label = @Translation("Update Notification As Read"),
 *   type = "node",
 *   confirm = TRUE
 * )
 */

class NotificationRead extends ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute(ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL) {
    $nid = $entity->id();
    $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    if ($nid) {
      $connection = \Drupal::database();
      $connection->delete('notifications')
      ->condition('entity_id', $nid)
      ->condition('entity_uid', $uid)
      ->execute();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
   \Drupal::logger('test')->warning(print_r("test", TRUE));
   if ($object instanceof Node) {
    return True;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Working]

[image: Not Working]

Answer (score 0):

This line means that you can only use your action on Nodes, and not any other entity type:

```
*  type = "node",
```

Remove this line, clear your registry, and you will be able to apply your action to other entity types as well.